# Does the Kato-Ponce estimate hold on manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Recall the Kato-Ponce estimate for fractional powers of the operator $J = (1-\Delta)$,
$$ \| J^s(fg) \|_{L^r} \lesssim \| J^s f \|_{L^{p_1}} \| g \|_{L^{q_1}} + \| J^s g \|_{L^{p_2}} \| f \|_{L^{q_2}}, $$
where $\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p_1} + \frac{1}{q_1} = \frac{1}{p_2} + \frac{1}{q_2}$, $1<r<\infty$, $1<p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2 <\infty$, and $s>0$ need not be an integer. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ this is well-established, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01780 .

Is it known that this estimate also holds on smooth compact manifolds?

In this [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03605309308820994) (Lemma 3.1) Sogge states the above estimate on smooth compact manifolds, but references the original [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160410704) of Kato-Ponce which is on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it somehow obvious that it extends easily to compact manifolds?

Comment: My guess is that you can use a partition of unity to reduce it to the Euclidean case. Although the operator isn’t local, it’s a pseudodiiferential operator, which should be enough to make it work.